# How can I get the client id from a request with a Client Credentials Grant Token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using Client Credentials Grant Token
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens)
and I'm looking to get the client id from a request where a Bearer Authorization header is set.
Is there a simple way to get this id?

Comment: you can get user like this `$request->user()`, logged in user is attached in `$request` variable

Comment: I don't think there is a user, since it is using client credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up setting client id as a request variable in my own CheckClientCredentials class. 
I copied vendor/laravel/passport/src/Http/Middleware/CheckClientController.php into app/Http/Middleware/CheckClientController.php and updated the handle method to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
{
    $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

    try {
        $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
    } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
        throw new AuthenticationException;
    }

    $request["oauth_client_id"] = $psr->getAttribute('oauth_client_id');

    $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);

    return $next($request);
}
```

I then updated the references to CheckClientCredentials in app/Http/Kernel.php
I can then grab the client id in my controllers using $request["oauth_client_id"].